# jQuery plugin: Prevent override options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

i did a custom plugin to add common functionality and validations to [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin. This is a resume so you can get the idea.

```
$.fn.myCustomUpload = function(options) {

    if (!$(this).is('input:file')) {
        return false;
    }

    $(this).fileupload({
        maxChunkSize: options.maxChunkSize,
        maxFileSize: options.maxFileSize,
        acceptFileTypes: options.allowedTypes,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',

        add: function (e, data) {
            // common validations
        },

        start: function (e) {
            // foo
            if (options.onUploadStart) {
                options.onUploadStart();
            }
        },

        fail: function(e, data) {
            // foo
            if (options.onUploadError) {
                options.onUploadError(result);
            }
        },

        done: function(e, data) {
            // foo
            if (options.onUploadDone) {
                options.onUploadDone(media_data);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The thing is that I made validations or process data, and return the results with callbacks. But, I notice that the callbacks were override with the next call to the plugin.. So, I upload a file in one place, and re the result show in another! What i'm doing wrong?

Should I need to store the options to each input element, like `.data()`?

EDIT 2: Fiddle of the html, and JS structure (not functional)
https://jsfiddle.net/a6axfm3v/

EDIT: I use this plugin in two ways

```
$input.myCustomUpload({
    // ...
    onUploadStart: this.onNewPostUploadStart.bind(this),
    onUploadProgress: this.onNewPostUploadProgress.bind(this), //this reference to my object
    onUploadError: this.onNewPostUploadError.bind(this),
    // ...
});
$uploads_buttons = $container.find('._attach_image');

$uploads_buttons.each(function() {
    var $upload_button = $(this);
    var $parent = $upload_button.parents('._post-container');

    $upload_button.myCustomUpload({ /*options, callbacks, etc*/});
});
```

`$input` has their own callbacks, and `$uploads_buttons` all have the same, but different that the `$input` ones..

Thanks.

Comment: Are you by chance using the same options object for multiple, different, invocations of this plugin, modifying the same object between the two?

Comment: Could you please show us how you're calling $(...).myCustomUpload?

Comment: _"But, I notice that the callbacks were override with the next call to the plugin"_ You are calling `.fileupload()` at each `.myCustomUpload()` call. Why do you need to call `.myCustomUpload()` more than once per element?

Comment: I believe it is usually the case that a plugin will take the options provided to it and $.extend({}, options) to create a local copy of them.  So that if the contents of the original object are changed, they will not affect the local copy

Comment: Side note, within jQuery.fn `this` is already a jquery object.  No need to wrap it in $()

Comment: Thanks guys, I edit the post to add more information about the way i'm using the plugin

Comment: _"`$input` has their own callbacks, and `$uploads_buttons` all have the same, but different that the `$input ones`"_ is not clear. What is `$input` and what is `$upload_buttons`?

Comment: Ok, to make it clear, we will asume that all buttons (there are more than one in the page) have different callbacks and options.. ($uploads buttons) all have the same, but is not relevant @guest271314

Comment: What do you mean by "buttons"? Can you include HTML at Question? Is `$input` and `$upload_button` the same element?

Comment: $uploads_buttons it's a collection of <input type="file" /> where i attach the fileuploader() plugin @guest271314

Comment: What is `$input`? Is `$input` the same collection of `<input type="file" />` elements as `$upload_buttons`?

Comment: Nope, this is another separate input.. is not in the same collection, has there own ID, meanwhile the other I find by the class, as I mention in the question.

Comment: In the code above you commented out what exactly you are passing in as the options to the method, which is the primary question that some of us had.

Comment: _"Nope, this is another separate input"_ How many different `<input type="file">` elements exist at HTML? What is purpose of `if (!$(this).is('input:file')) {
        return false;
    }`? Can you include HTML at Question and create a stacksnippet to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here i made a fiddle to get an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/a6axfm3v/ @guest271314

Comment: @mauriblint The JavaScript at linked jsfiddle is different from JavaScript at Question. You call `$input.myCustomUpload()` within `.each()`, not `$upload_button.myCustomUpload()`

Comment: Sorry, i make it so fast, $upload_button.myCustomUpload() is the right way.. i will update the fiddle

Comment: _"$upload_button.myCustomUpload() is the right way."_ Then the code should return expected result, yes?

Comment: Nope, in the fiddle it was just a typo, i still having the same issue..